# Layout from own component isn't correctly displayed in TabPane

Tags: layout, javafx, javafx-8

I have a own component (extended TextField). When I display the component in an AnchorPane the layout from the component is correctly displayed. But when I display the component in a TabPane then the first time when the component is shown the layout isn't correct rendered.

Screenshot:
[Own component in an AnchorPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1TmF.png)

Screenshot:
[Own component in a TabPane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsJ16.png)

Here a MCVE:

```
import static javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_PREF_SIZE;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Separator;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Naoghuman
 */
public class ExtendedComponentsMCVE extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ExtendedTextField extendedTextField = new ExtendedTextField();

//        OnlyAnchorPane oap = new OnlyAnchorPane(extendedTextField);
//        Scene scene = new Scene(oap, 800, 600);

        TabAnchorPane tap = new TabAnchorPane(extendedTextField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tap, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Demo Extended Components");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // ExtendedTextField #######################################################
    class ExtendedTextField extends HBox {

        private BooleanProperty configureCheckBoxProperty;
        private BooleanProperty configureLeftLabelProperty;
        private BooleanProperty configureTopLabelProperty;

        private CheckBox cbReadOnly;
        private Label lLeft;
        private Label lTop;
        private TextField tfText;
        private VBox vBox;

        private String lastUserInput = ""; // NOI18N

        ExtendedTextField() {
            super();

            this.init();
        }

        private void init() {
            // vbox
            super.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_LEFT);
            super.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgreen;");

            // left label
            configureLeftLabelProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(Boolean.TRUE);
            lLeft = new Label("<left>"); // NOI18N
            lLeft.setMaxHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
            lLeft.setMinHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
            lLeft.visibleProperty().bind(configureLeftLabelProperty);
            lLeft.managedProperty().bind(configureLeftLabelProperty);
            super.getChildren().add(lLeft);

            // checkbox
            configureCheckBoxProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(Boolean.TRUE);
            cbReadOnly = new CheckBox();
            cbReadOnly.setMaxHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
            cbReadOnly.setMinHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
            cbReadOnly.visibleProperty().bind(configureCheckBoxProperty);
            cbReadOnly.managedProperty().bind(configureCheckBoxProperty);
            super.getChildren().add(cbReadOnly);

            // vbox
            vBox = new VBox();
            HBox.setHgrow(vBox, Priority.ALWAYS);

            // top label
            configureTopLabelProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(Boolean.TRUE);
            lTop = new Label("<top>"); // NOI18N
            lTop.visibleProperty().bind(configureTopLabelProperty);
            lTop.managedProperty().bind(configureTopLabelProperty);
            vBox.getChildren().add(lTop);

            // textfield
            tfText = new TextField(lastUserInput);
            tfText.disableProperty().bind(cbReadOnly.selectedProperty().not());
            lLeft.prefHeightProperty().bind(tfText.heightProperty());
            cbReadOnly.prefHeightProperty().bind(tfText.heightProperty());
            vBox.getChildren().add(tfText);

            super.getChildren().add(vBox);
        }

        public void setCheckBoxSelected(Boolean selected) {
            cbReadOnly.setSelected(selected);

            if (selected) {
                tfText.setText(lastUserInput);
            }
            else {
                lastUserInput = tfText.getText();
                tfText.setText(null);
            }
        }

        public void setCheckBoxVisibleManaged(Boolean visible) {
            configureCheckBoxProperty.setValue(visible);
        }

        public void setLeftLabelVisibleManaged(boolean selected) {
            configureLeftLabelProperty.setValue(selected);
        }

        public void setTopLabelVisibleManaged(boolean selected) {
            configureTopLabelProperty.setValue(selected);
        }

    }
    // ExtendedTextField #######################################################

    // OnlyAnchorPane ##########################################################
    class OnlyAnchorPane extends AnchorPane {
        OnlyAnchorPane(ExtendedTextField extendedTextField) {
            super();
            super.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLANCHEDALMOND;");

            // hbox
            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: KHAKI;");
            hbox.setSpacing(7.0d);
            hbox.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

            // extendedTextField
            VBox vbox = new VBox();
            vbox.getChildren().add(extendedTextField);
            HBox.setHgrow(vbox, Priority.ALWAYS);
            hbox.getChildren().add(vbox);

            // menu
            MenuVBox menu = new MenuVBox(extendedTextField);
            hbox.getChildren().add(menu);

            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(hbox, 14d);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(hbox, 14d);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(hbox, 14d);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hbox, 14d);
            super.getChildren().add(hbox);
        }
    }
    // OnlyAnchorPane ##########################################################

    // TabAnchorPane ###########################################################
    class TabAnchorPane extends AnchorPane {
        TabAnchorPane(ExtendedTextField extendedTextField) {
            super();
            super.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLANCHEDALMOND;");

            // tabpane
            TabPane tp = new TabPane();

            // tab
            Tab t = new Tab("TextField");
            t.setClosable(false);
            tp.getTabs().add(t);

            // hbox
            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: KHAKI;");
            hbox.setSpacing(7.0d);
            hbox.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

            // extendedTextField
            VBox vbox = new VBox();
            vbox.getChildren().add(extendedTextField);
            HBox.setHgrow(vbox, Priority.ALWAYS);
            hbox.getChildren().add(vbox);

            // menu
            MenuVBox menu = new MenuVBox(extendedTextField);
            hbox.getChildren().add(menu);
            t.setContent(hbox);

            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(tp, 14d);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(tp, 14d);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(tp, 14d);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(tp, 14d);
            super.getChildren().add(tp);
        }    
    }
    // TabAnchorPane ###########################################################

    // MenuVBox ################################################################
    class MenuVBox extends VBox {

        MenuVBox(ExtendedTextField extendedTextField) {
            super();
            super.setStyle("-fx-background-color: HONEYDEW;");

            super.setSpacing(7.0d);
            super.setMaxWidth(200.0d);
            super.setMinWidth(200.0d);
            super.setPrefWidth(200.0d);

            // show top label
            CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("Show top label");
            cb1.setSelected(true);
            cb1.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                extendedTextField.setTopLabelVisibleManaged(cb1.isSelected());
            });
            super.getChildren().add(cb1);

            // show left label
            CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox("Show left label");
            cb2.setSelected(true);
            cb2.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                extendedTextField.setLeftLabelVisibleManaged(cb2.isSelected());
            });
            super.getChildren().add(cb2);

            // seperator
            super.getChildren().add(new Separator());

            // select checkbox
            CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox("Select checkbox");
            cb3.setSelected(false);
            cb3.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                extendedTextField.setCheckBoxSelected(cb3.isSelected());
            });
            super.getChildren().add(cb3);

            // show checkbox
            CheckBox cb4 = new CheckBox("Show checkbox");
            cb4.setSelected(true);
            cb4.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
                extendedTextField.setCheckBoxVisibleManaged(cb4.isSelected());
            });
            super.getChildren().add(cb4);

        }
    }
    // MenuVBox ################################################################
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the problem of laying out maybe due to the fixed values you tried to give for related nodes:

```
lLeft.setMaxHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
lLeft.setMinHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

and

```
cbReadOnly.setMaxHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
cbReadOnly.setMinHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

This just a guess, but anyway you can manually request the renderer to layout the components just at the end of constructing of them via `runLater()`:

```
class ExtendedTextField extends HBox {
...
...

private void init() {
    ...

    Platform.runLater( ()->{
        requestLayout();
    });
}
...
}
```

BTW, I could not see any control that extends TextField ;)

Comment: Thx, request the layout do it. USE_PREF_SIZE is needed because of centering the components in the height (for example if the font-size from the TextField is changed). BTW its right, that in this example isn't a control which _extends_ a TextField. But I think as the name from the hole new component its okay :).